# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to com.rey.material.widget.ImageView

Tags: java, xml

I want to load an URL into an imageView located in a different layout than the current activity layout.

I don't know what's this com.rey.material package and where it comes from. I assume maybe it is used by the template i've been importing.
Do you have an idea on how to fix this problem ?

```
  theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int pos, long l) {
            // Unfold cell first then Change Stuff inside
            // toggle clicked cell state
            ((FoldingCell) view).toggle(false);
            // register in adapter that state for selected cell is toggled
            adapter.registerToggle(pos);

            final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
            final View cell = factory.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.head_image);
            Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(image);



        }
    });
```

This is the layout that wraps everything together :

```
<com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:folding-cell="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    folding-cell:additionalFlipsCount="2"
    folding-cell:animationDuration="1300"
    folding-cell:backSideColor="@color/bgBackSideColor"
    folding-cell:cameraHeight="30">

    <!-- CONTENT (UNFOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times BIGGER than content layout bellow)-->
    <include layout="@layout/cell_content_layout" />

    <!-- TITLE (FOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times SMALLER than content layout above) -->
    <include layout="@layout/cell_title_layout" />

</com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>
```

And this is the layout containing the specific imageView :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/head_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/head_image" />

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, it was a misclick on my part:

When importing packages for `ImageView`, I clicked the first package instead of the usual one, which caused this problem. **Solution:**

Replace

```
import com.rey.material.widget.ImageView
```

with

```
import android.widget.ImageView
```

Answer (score 0):

I know i am late to the party, but just in case some is banging his head for same problem, here is one possible solution that worked for me when i was trying to add zoom functionality in my pager adapter images

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/head_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/head_image" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In the above code, just Replace `<ImageView` with `<com.yourPackage.TouchImageView`.

**TouchImageView**  (or any other class) is a custom class (you need to make)which should extend **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView**